# tune2fs: what time zone is the date created in and is it possible to change it?

Tags: date, e2fsprogs

I have been using tune2fs to determine the age of my Linux distribution installations but without knowing the time zone the date in it is less useful. The exact command I am using is from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/221377/how-to-determine-the-age-of-a-linux-system-since-installation), here it is just for the sake of clarity:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda3 | grep created | sed 's/.*created\:\s*//g'
```

but the output is of the form:

```
Fri Jun 23 23:59:22 2017
```

Note how there is no time zone mentioned. But `date` returns output of the form:

```
Sun Jul 23 17:58:18 AEST 2017
```

Notice how the time zone AEST is mentioned. I have read the man page of [`tune2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs). I have searched for "date", "created", "time" in it using my Web browser's find utility and I haven't found a single mention of the time zone of the date format, or if there is a way to manually set it. I have run DuckDuckGo searches for "tune2fs date" and "tune2fs timezone" and I looked at the top five results and couldn't find anything relevant in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date seems to be displayed in the local system time zone at the time it was created.

e.g. my /boot partition is ext4 on raid-1 (/dev/md0), created when I replaced my boot drives with 4 SSDs and converted to root on ZFS last year.  I kept a /boot ext4 partition in case of emergency.

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/md0 | sed -n -e 's/.*created\:\s*//gp'
Sat Oct  8 16:38:45 2016

# TZ=UTC tune2fs -l /dev/md0 | sed -n -e 's/.*created\:\s*//gp'
Sat Oct  8 05:38:45 2016
```

I'm also on the east coast of Australia (Melbourne), and the difference between 16:38 and 05:38 is 11 hours, which is correct for AEDT (daylight savings starts in October for those states which observe it)

---

BTW, it's almost never necessary to pipe the output of grep into either sed or awk.  both can already do regexp pattern matches.  an awk example might look like this:

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/md0 | awk -F': +' '/created/ {print $2}'
Sat Oct  8 16:38:45 2016
```

Answer (score 4):

The time is stored as a Unix epoch time (see `s_mkfs_time` in the [superblock](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block)), not as a calendar date, so it's timezone independent.

When displaying it, `tune2fs` converts it to a calendar/human date to give you a representation meaningful to you, in your time zone.

To get the time in UTC, run it with:

```
TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l /dev/sda3 |
  sed -n 's/^Filesystem created: *//p'
```

That is telling `tune2fs` that your timezone is UTC (with 0 offset from UTC).

I've added LC_ALL=C to make sure the `Filesystem created` is returned in English and the date is still displayed in the US-English style regardless of the locale of the user (in case `e2fsprogs` are internationalised in the future).

Since the `S_mkfs_time` is at offset 0x108 in the superblock and the superblock starts at offset 0x400 within the block device, you can also retrieve that epoch time by hand:

```
od -vAn -j 0x508 -N4 < /dev/sda3
```

And convert it in the format you like:

```
$ date --iso-8601=s -d "@$(od -An -j0x508 -N4 -tu4 < /some/device)"
2017-07-23T12:20:22+01:00
$ date -u --iso-8601=s -d "@$(od -An -j0x508 -N4 -tu4 < /some/device)"
2017-07-23T11:20:22+00:00
```